# Fluid will not lie flat on obstacle

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Working in Blender 2.73 I have created a fountain and assigned it as a fluid obstacle with a 0.054 partial slip and an impact factor of 1.  Why when the fluid interacts with the obstacle, it creates a mushroom type effect and will not lie flat on the surface and run over the edges?  Similarly, in the pooling section of the obstacle why does the fluid create a curl and not roll over the edge?  I have tried multiple settings and resolution adjustments.  Attached is a screenshot of the domain settings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: There are a couple problems. Your fluid object has inverted normals. I'm not exactly sure why this is, but try selecting all the vertices in your domain object and press Ctrl N in edit mode, then re-baking. As for the collision behavior, this is a consequence of baking with low resolution. Try baking at e.g. 150 and see if it looks any better.

Comment: gandalf3 thank you for your suggestion.  I am pretty new to blender.  I did try upping the rest to 150 and checking the box to "Make Normals Consistent" Inside.  Sadly altering the normals did not work.

Comment: Maybe set the normals of the obstacles?